# C# LINQ TimeSpan Average Days

Tags: c#, linq, timespan

I am learning LINQ and want a LINQ query that is the equivalent of the following code.

The IEnumerable list contains a sorted list of dates:  Oldest to newest.

The code below derives `TimeSpan`s by subtracting the array's zeroth element date from array's first element date, the first element date from the 2nd, 2nd from the 3rd and so on.  The `TimeSpan.Days` are then averaged elsewhere in the code.

I trust a LINQ query would not require the construction of an array.  The `IEnumerable<DateTime>` structure could be used as the data source.

```
 IEnumerable<DateTime> list; // contains a sorted list of oldest to newest dates

// build DateTime array 

 DateTime[] datesArray = null;
 TimeSpan ts;
 List<int> daysList = new List<int>();

 datesArray = (from dt in list
               select dt).ToArray();

// loop through the array and derive the TimeSpan by subtracting the previous date,
// contained in the previous array element, from the date in the current array element.
// start the loop at element 1.

 for (int i = 1; i < list.Count(); i++)
 {
     ts = datesArray[i].Subtract(datesArray[i - 1]); // ts is a TimeSpan type
     daysList.Add(ts.Days);
     // add the TimeSpan.Days to a List<int> for averaging elsewhere.
 }
```

Thank you,

Scott

Comment: `(from dt in list select dt).ToArray()` is better written as `list.ToArray()`

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
double averageDays = list
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Zip(list, (next, prev) => (double)next.Subtract(prev).Days)
                     .Average();
```

Do note that this is a *lossy* average. Are you sure you don't want to use `TotalDays` instead?

EDIT:

The way this works is to overlay the sequence with a 'one-deferred' version of the sequence,  which makes it easy to calculate consecutive deltas. Then it's just a matter of averaging the deltas up to produce the result.

For comparison, a 'faithful' translation of your existing code would look like:

```
double averageDays = Enumerable
                     .Range(1, list.Count - 1)
                     .Average(i => (double)list[i].Subtract(list[i - 1]).Days);
```

Comment: `Zip` seems a bit unnecessary here, it should be doable with `Aggregate`.

Comment: ...but it's considerably easier to understand the intent of the code. Handy though `Aggregate` is, it makes ugly code that's non-obvious.

Comment: Linq Zip is a Framework 4.0.  I need a Framework 3.5 or lower solution.  I also need just a list of the individual days deltas for statistical analysis more than Average.

Comment: @scottL: How about the second solution? Replace `Average` with `Select` to get the individual deltas. Of course, you could implement `Zip` yourself; it's quite easy. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx

Comment: Got it.  I simply did as you suggested and replaced the Average with Select.  That was the solution I sought.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an average only then you do not need to check all elements in the list. You need only the first one and the last one.

```
var period = list.Last() - list.First();
var averageDays = (double)period.TotalDays / (list.Count() - 1);
```

Comment: Do note that the OP is computing the average of `DeltaD.Days`. The inherent rounding there means it is different from this approach.

Comment: Thank you Sergey.  Your approach was mathematically correct and easier given the information I provided.  However, I needed the individal days deltas for other Statistical analysis:  Mode, etc, which is information I did not provide in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is arranged into a more Lispy indentation style to emphasize the functional style and avoid running off into scrollbar-land on the right side of the page.

```
list.Skip(1)
    .Aggregate(new { Previous = list.FirstOrDefault(), 
                     Sum = 0.0,
                     Count = 0 },
               (a, n) => new { Previous = n,
                               Sum = a.Sum + (n - a.Previous).Days,
                               Count = a.Count + 1 },
               a => a.Sum / a.Count)
```

Comment: If the intention is to skip the first item, shouldn't you call .Skip(1) in the seed of Aggregate as well?

Comment: I suspect that you want `TotalDays`, seeing as how you defined `Sum` as a `double`.

Comment: @vcsjones: the first item is preloaded into the seed, that's why it's being skipped.

Comment: @Gabe: `Sum` is a `double` to avoid overflow issues and because the average is to be returned as one.  I left `Days` alone because the original code used it.

Comment: Thank you all for answering the question.  I needed the individual days deltas for more than Average calculations.  I perform Statistical Mode and ohter calculations on the